# Error while inserting pointer to a vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have the following CPP code snippet and the associated error message:

*Code snippet*

```
    struct node{
            char charVal;
            bool childNode;
            struct node *leftChild;
            struct node *rightChild;
    };
    vector<std::pair<int,struct node*> > nodeCountList;
    struct node *nodePtr = new struct node;
    nodeCountList.push_back(1,nodePtr);
```

*Error message*

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::pair<int, node*>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, node*> > >::push_back(int&, node*&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:602: note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::pair<int, node*>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<int, node*> >]
```

Please help me troubleshoot the error message.

cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to push a std::pair.

```
nodeCountList.push_back(std::make_pair(1,nodePtr));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass two arguments to `nodeCountList.push_back`, which only accepts one argument. Instead, first create a `std::pair` with the two items you want in it. Then, call `nodeCountList.push_back` with that `std::pair` as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turining "node" into a type first, and then using your template? Maybe this will work better.